# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: LtklSubmitInfo of: gov.siapuppatk.model.LtklSubmitInfoDetail

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, native

I have problem to SELECT data by D_TRANSAKSI.
this is my query :

```
String SQL = "SELECT a.zip_file_name, a.ltkl_count, a.ltkl_count_process, b.status, a.sent_date, a.receive_date" +
                " FROM t_ltkl_submit_info a" +
                " JOIN t_ltkl_submit_info_det b" +
                " ON a.id = b.id_submit_info" +
                " JOIN t_ltkl c" +
                " ON a.zip_file_name = c.zip_file_name" +
                " JOIN t_kupu_in d" +
                " ON c.id_kupu_incoming = d.id_kupu_incoming" +
                " JOIN t_kupu_in_transaksi e" +
                " ON d.id_kupu_incoming = e.id_kupu_incoming" +
                " WHERE e.d_transaksi = :d_transaksi";

    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(SQL);
    query.setParameter("d_transaksi", d_transaksi);
```

The alias of entity:

```
query.addEntity("a", LtklSubmitInfo.class);
    query.addEntity("b", LtklSubmitInfoDetail.class);
    query.addEntity("c",TLtkl.class);
    query.addEntity("d", TKupuIncoming.class);
    query.addEntity("e", TKupuIncomingTransaksi.class);
```

For join table :

```
query.addJoin("a", "b.LtklSubmitInfo");
        query.addJoin("a", "c.LtklSubmitInfo");
        query.addJoin("c", "d.TLtkl");
        query.addJoin("d", "e.TKupuIncoming");
```

End the Error is:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: LtklSubmitInfo of: gov.siapuppatk.model.LtklSubmitInfoDetail
>       org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:44)
>       org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:38)
>       org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3439)
>       org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.(CustomLoader.java:151)
>       org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1688)
>       org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
>       org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
>       gov.siapuppatk.dao.impl.LtklSubmitInfoDaoImpl.setDataTanggalTransaksi(LtklSubmitInfoDaoImpl.java:149)
>       gov.siapuppatk.service.LtklSubmitInfoService.loadDataTanggalTransaksi(LtklSubmitInfoService.java:133)
>       gov.siapuppatk.service.LtklSubmitInfoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d8bedee7.invoke()
>       org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
>       org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>       org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
>       gov.siapuppatk.service.LtklSubmitInfoService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$45417895.loadDataTanggalTransaksi()
>       gov.siapuppatk.controller.CekSubmitController.viewHistoryLtkl(CekSubmitController.java:127)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

this is my controller :

```
if (tdate != null){
                if (!tdate.equals("")){
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    //tanggalTransaksi = StringHelper.toDate(tdate);
                    tanggalTransaksi = dateFormat.parse(tdate);
                    System.out.println("tanggal nih keluar dong " + tanggalTransaksi);

                    LtklSubmitInfoDto ltklsubmitDto = null;
                    ltklsubmitDto = this.ltklSubmitInfoService.loadDataTanggalTransaksi(filter,tanggalTransaksi);

                }
                model.addObject("tdate", tanggalTransaksi);
```

This is my service :

```
public LtklSubmitInfoDto loadDataTanggalTransaksi (FilterCriteria filterCriteria, Date dTransaksi){
    System.out.println("select data by d_transaksi");
    LtklSubmitInfoDto ltklSubmitDto = new LtklSubmitInfoDto();
    ltklSubmitDto.setdTransaksi((Date) ltklSubmitInfoDao.setDataTanggalTransaksi(dTransaksi));
    return ltklSubmitDto;
}
```

This is my JSP :

```
<label style="display: inline-block; width:100px;">Tanggal Transaksi</label>
                <lable style="display: inline-block; width:10px;">:</lable>
                <input type="text" size="10" name="tdate" id="dateValue3" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${tanggalTransaksi}" pattern='dd/MM/yyyy'/>" />
                <img id='datepick3' src="assets/ico/calendar.png"/>
                <br/>
```

I try to fixed it but it's not solved.

Thanks in advance